# SalesForce Notifications - Reliable Integration

Tags: salesforce, reliability

I need to develop a system that is listening to the changes happened with SalesForce objects and transfers them to my end.

Initially I considered *SalesForce Streaming API* that allows exactly that - create a **push topic** that subscribes to objects **notifications** and later have a set of clients that are reading them using long polling.

However such approach doesn't guarantee durability and reliable delivery of notifications - which I am in need.

What will be the architecture allowing to implement the same functionality in reliable way?

---

One approach I have in mind is create  a Force.com applications that uses SalesForce triggers to subscribe to notifications and later just sends them using HTTPS to the cloud or my Data Server. Will this be a valid option - or are there any better ones?

Answer (score 2):

I two very good questions on salesforce.stackexchange.com covering this very topic in details:

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16587/integrating-a-real-time-notification-application-with-salesforce

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/20600/best-approach-for-a-package-to-respond-to-dml-events-dynamically-without-object

Comment: didn't quite follow on what could be a good workaround for reliability issues with salesforce streaming api? Could you summarize?